# Docker: check if RabbitMQ is ready to be subscribed?

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, rabbitmq

This question is similar to [the one I posted about Postgre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56251063/how-to-determine-whether-postgresql-running-in-a-docker-container-is-done-initia).

Basically, I setup a program that leverage the .NET Docker client and run the RabbitMQ image (with the management plugin included) and then via the EasyNetQ uses RabbitMQ to subscribe and and send a message on the same queue.

```
public static class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(params string[] args)
    {
        var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

        var configuration = new Configuration();
        configurationBuilder.Build().Bind(configuration);

        var client = new DockerClientConfiguration(DockerUris.DefaultLocalApi).CreateClient();

        var containers = await client.Containers.SearchByNameAsync(configuration.ContainerName);
        var container = containers.SingleOrDefault();
        if (container != null)
        {
            await client.Containers.StopAndRemoveContainerAsync(container.ID);
            await client.Volumes.RemoveAsync(container.Mounts.Select(x => x.Name));
        }

        var createdContainer = await client.Containers.RunContainerAsync(new CreateContainerParameters
        {
            Image = configuration.ImageName,
            HostConfig = new HostConfig
            {
                PortBindings = new Dictionary<string, IList<PortBinding>>
                {
                    {$"{configuration.QueueContainerPort}/{configuration.QueueContainerPortProtocol}", 
                        new List<PortBinding>
                        {
                            new PortBinding { HostPort = configuration.QueueHostPort }
                        }
                    },
                    {$"{configuration.ManagementContainerPort}/{configuration.ManagementContainerPortProtocol}", 
                        new List<PortBinding>
                        {
                            new PortBinding { HostPort = configuration.ManagementHostPort }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            Env = new List<string>
            {
                $"RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER={configuration.Username}",
                $"RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS={configuration.Password}"
            },
            Name = configuration.ContainerName
        });

        // Thread.Sleep(2000);

        var bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=localhost");

        await bus.PubSub.SubscribeAsync<TextMessage>("sub", message =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message.Text);
        });

        await bus.PubSub.PublishAsync<TextMessage>(new TextMessage
        {
            Text = "Michelle"
        });

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class TextMessage
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

It seems that the RabbitMQ is not fully ready to be subscribed to if I run my program above (that is if `// Thread.Sleep(2000);` is not commented out), I get the following exception:

```cs
System.TimeoutException: The operation requested on PersistentChannel timed out
  at at EasyNetQ.Producer.PersistentChannel.InvokeChannelAction(Action`1 channelAction)
  at at EasyNetQ.Producer.ClientCommandDispatcherSingleton.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`1.<InvokeAsync>b__0()
  at at EasyNetQ.RabbitAdvancedBus.QueueDeclareAsync(String name, Action`1 configure, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  at at EasyNetQ.Producer.DefaultPubSub.SubscribeAsyncInternal[T](String subscriptionId, Func`3 onMessage, Action`1 configure, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I am wondering what kind of command I can run in the container in order to know that RabbitMQ is fully ready to be subscribed to.

Comment: Does the client lib allow for "health-check calls"?

Comment: @Fildor in theory yes, but in my other related question I explained it seems that there is a bug in regard to health check calls, so instead I performed myself the command to check whether Postgre was ready or not

Comment: Ah, I see. OK. In that case I'd go for a warm-up with try and error.

Comment: can you show your dockerfile? I think this can be done during startup or set priority during boot time for each

Comment: @Adiii this has nothing to do with the dockerfile, I just start a new container based on an image. Just looking for a command that returns a certain value upon RabbitMQ initialization